# Conditional probability of an inspector having prior training, given the failure to detect a weapon

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> 23. Ninety percent of new airport-security personnel have had prior training in weapon detection. During their first month on the job, personnel without prior training fail to detect a weapon 3% of the time, while those with prior training fail only 0.5% of the time. What is the probability a new airport-security employee, who fails to detect a weapon during the first month on the job, has had prior training in weapon detection?

From  Discrete Math: An Applied Introduction

Let:
$A$: Employee had prior training
$\lnot A:$ Employee has NO prior training
$B$: Fail to detect weapon

$Pr(A)$: 0.9
$Pr(\lnot A)$:0.1
$Pr(B)$: ?

"Personnel without prior training fail to detect a weapon 3% of the time."
I translate this to $Pr(B|\lnot A)$ = 0.03.

"Those with prior training fail only 0.5% of the time."
I translate this to $Pr(B|A)$ = 0.005.

The first problem I run into is that I'm not sure what '?' is supposed to be.

The second problems is I'm having trouble translating the main question, "What is the probability a new airport-security employee, who fails to detect a weapon during the first month on the job, has had prior training in weapon detection?" into from using $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You're confused by the question mark? For the second question - think of this "it is given that the new employee has failed to detect a weapon. Knowing this, what is the probability that this new employee had prior training"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can have an employee fail to detect.  She could have prior training $(90\%)$ and fail to detect $(0.5\%)$, so $0.45\%$ total chance.  Or she could not have prior training $(10\%)$  and fail to detect $(3\%)$, so $0.3\%$ total chance.

So we are looking for $$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{.45\%}{.45\%+.3\%}$$

And $P(B)$ in your case would be $.45\%+.3\%$ I believe.

Editing to add:$P(B)=P(B\cap A)+P(B\cap A')=.45\%+.3\%$

Comment: can you explain the 0.45% from the 90% and .5%?

Comment: Just the product of the two.  Since it's the probability both happen.